# How to detect "ALT + TAB" key event in SWT Shell?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to detect the key event <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key in SWT Shell. At the time of tab key pressed it must be required to pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.
I have tried using the following but its not detect <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Display display = new Display ();
    final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    final Color green = display.getSystemColor (SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
    final Color orig = shell.getBackground();

    display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if(((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) == SWT.ALT) && (e.keyCode == SWT.TAB))
            {
                System.out.println("From Display I am the Key down !!" );
            }
        }
    });
    shell.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
          if(((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) == SWT.ALT) && (e.keyCode == SWT.TAB))
          {
              shell.setBackground(orig);
              System.out.println("Key up ALT +TAB Detact !!");
          }
      }
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          if(((e.stateMask & SWT.ALT) == SWT.ALT) && (e.keyCode ==  SWT.TAB))
          {
              shell.setBackground(green);
              System.out.println("Key down  ALT +TAB Detact!!");
          }
      }
   });
    shell.setSize (200, 200);
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your `keyReleased` code - comparing SWT.ALT with SWT.CTRL.

Comment: The `keyPressed` event works for me on macOS. If you are using Windows I would guess that the OS never sends the Alt+Tab event to the app.

Comment: @greg-449: Yes you are right I am using windows OS. How to possible detach a this event?

Comment: Windows itself uses this keybinding. Even if you *could* handle this event yourself, you should avoid trying to.